# Making sub category in laravel website

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

so i want to expand my site to have like region site, so when user open my site it will be ask to select which region he/she interested into and lets just say he interesting in London, then the site will generate a webpage that already all content related to that region...

i tried to just do the same way i create administrator page by group them in this route

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'admins','before' => 'auth'),function(){
    Route::resource('partner','AdminPartnerController',array('except' => array('show')));
    Route::get('partner/index_kategori/{id}',array(
        'as' => 'admins.partner.index_kategori',
        'uses' => 'AdminPartnerController@index_kategori'
});
```

but it's mean that i need to create a different controller function for each region i gonna create, so it's not very efficient.

what comes to my mind is just like making

```
www.websiteadress.com/region
```

so how i can catch that "/region" and add that value into each my function in controller? how to build that kind of routes?

**update:**

to make it more easily to understand, what become my problem is like i have this normal route:

```
Route::get('product/{id}',array( 'as' => 'product','uses' => 'PublicController@product'));
```

what this route do is pretty straight foward, when i type

```
www.websiteadress.com/product/12
```

it will open the product page for number 12, so my problem is if i add like this

```
www.websiteadress.com/Asia/product/12
```

how i make my PublicController to catch Asia and later in my product function i will just process that..?

Comment: Maybe make the route like this: `Route::get('product/{country}/{id}',array( 'as' => 'product','uses' => 'PublicController@product'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after searching for days and asking around, i finally getting the best solution to answer my own question and i willing to share it to here, so someday maybe there is other people who want to do what want to...

so first in the route just create like this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{region}'], function(){
    Route::get('member',array('as' => 'member','uses' => 'PublicController@member'));
});
```

and what this route do is just group it into prefix with value is in region variable and then i set the get route to where the controller will use to show the page and also taking region value into use

and then in my PublicController

```
public function sitemap($region){
  if($region =='london'){
     //do something
  }else{
    //do something
  }
}
```

and so there it is.. i can get those region value from prefix and use it. in my case i use it to show certain page with different content.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you don't need to create controller for each region. You want to use simple route with a variable:

```
Route::get('region/{region}', 'RegionController@show');
```

And just one controller for all regions:

```
public function show ($region)
{
    // Logic here
    return view('region.show', compact(['region']));
}
```

So, when user will load `http://example.com/region/London`, `show` action will have `London` in `$region` variable.

Comment: thank you, but please kindly see my updated post... to get a better understanding